# converting buffer to string

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my data:

```
"buffer": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            8,
            4,
            18,
            32,
            203,
            243,
            203,
            190,
            254,
            80,
            185,
            227,
            225,
            187,
            114,
            219,
            243,
            87,
            83,
            254,
            248,
            95,
            139,
            1,
            26,
            198,
            149,
            158,
            30,
            44,
            146,
            237,
            166,
            70,
            199,
            9,
            26,
            32,
            138,
            251,
            102,
            14,
            230,
            244,
            102,
            250,
            142,
            53,
            210,
            190,
            9,
            23,
            169,
            98,
            14,
            156,
            148,
            99,
            168,
            204,
            145,
            108,
            191,
            223,
            189,
            58,
            202,
            61,
            52,
            254
        ]
    },
```

I want to convert it to a string. So far tried below mentioned things:

1. .toString()
2. .new String(buffer)
3. String.fromCharCode.apply(null, buffer)
4. buffer.map(c => String.fromCharCode(c)).join('') etc

Btw I have no access to data since when I try to access data it throws undefined so I pass the complete object which in this case is buffer to parse which is not returning the proper result. It is returning `"\b Ì jQßô\f:l{Ê­3DZz²ú_¿;t_ ¹ÐÇævËçÕ§MAjHríþ;!/Ýdãi",`

Can someone help me with what it is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to share the code where you get the buffer

Comment: `which is not returning the proper result.` So what _is_ the proper result? Those numbers don't look like they'd result in readable ascii.

Comment: @TienDuong I get the buffer as part of the response from fabric node js sdk when I call of its function.

Comment: There's no specific code as such. Its just a function call. `let response = await channel.queryInfo(peer, true);` Here's the function call if this helps

Comment: @tkausl yeah, I did not consider that possibility.  It could be returning whatever i am getting right now.

Comment: So when you ```console.log(response)```. You got the above buffer?

Comment: yes. This is the exact response. https://pastebin.com/cGd7XTrn @TienDuong

Comment: Why do you want to convert the buffer to string?

Comment: @TienDuong Well the buffer or byte array to be exact is supposed to contain data which I want.

Comment: In that case, what you want is decoding the buffer then get data from the decoded buffer instead of converting the buffer to string. Because the buffer is ```BlockHash``` of a ```Blockchain``` so it has been encoded. 
```A block hash is calculated by hashing over the concatenated ASN.1 encoded bytes of: the block number, previous block hash, and current block data hash. It's the chain of the block hashs that guarantees the immutability of the ledger```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the encoding to the `.toString()` function like in thew following example:

```
foo.toString('utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let data = {"buffer": {
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": [
        8,
        4,
        18,
        32,
        203,
        243,
        203,
        190,
        254,
        80,
        185,
        227,
        225,
        187,
        114,
        219,
        243,
        87,
        83,
        254,
        248,
        95,
        139,
        1,
        26,
        198,
        149,
        158,
        30,
        44,
        146,
        237,
        166,
        70,
        199,
        9,
        26,
        32,
        138,
        251,
        102,
        14,
        230,
        244,
        102,
        250,
        142,
        53,
        210,
        190,
        9,
        23,
        169,
        98,
        14,
        156,
        148,
        99,
        168,
        204,
        145,
        108,
        191,
        223,
        189,
        58,
        202,
        61,
        52,
        254
    ]
}}
let newstr = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(newstr)
console.log(JSON.parse(newstr).buffer.data)
```